# pd.read_csv by default treats integers like floats

Tags: python, csv, pandas, integer

I have a `csv` that looks like (headers = first row):

```
name,a,a1,b,b1
arnold,300311,arnld01,300311,arnld01
sam,300713,sam01,300713,sam01
```

When I run:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
```

Columns `a` and `b` have a `.0` attached to the end like so:

```
df.head()

name,a,a1,b,b1
arnold,300311.0,arnld01,300311.0,arnld01
sam,300713.0,sam01,300713.0,sam01
```

Columns `a` and `b` are integers or blanks so why does `pd.read_csv()` treat them like floats and how do I ensure they are integers on the read?

Comment: What version of python and pandas are you using? I can't replicate this in Python 3.5.1 or Python 2.7.10 using Pandas `0.18.1`

Comment: What do you mean by "blanks"?  Do you mean `NaN` values?  If so, the column will need float dtype, as `NaN` is a float, not an integer.  You could probably selectively convert the non-`NaN` values to integers, but I don't think it would be advisable.  What benefit do you gain by having them as integers instead of floats?

Comment: Python version = 3.5.1 |Anaconda 2.5.0 (64-bit) and Pandas 0.18.1

Answer (score 21):

As [root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39666308/pd-read-csv-by-default-treats-integers-like-floats#comment66634324_39666308) mentioned in the comments, this is a limitation of Pandas (and Numpy). `NaN` is a float and the empty values you have in your CSV are NaN.

This is listed in the [gotchas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/gotchas.html#na-type-promotions) of pandas as well.

You can work around this in a few ways.

For the examples below I used the following to import the data - note that I added a row with an empty value in columns `a` and `b`

```
import pandas as pd
from StringIO import StringIO

data = """name,a,a1,b,b1
arnold,300311,arnld01,300311,arnld01
sam,300713,sam01,300713,sam01
test,,test01,,test01"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep=",")
```

#### Drop NaN rows

Your first option is to drop rows that contain this `NaN` value. The downside of this, is that you lose the entire row. After getting your data into a dataframe, run this:

```
df.dropna(inplace=True)
df.a = df.a.astype(int)
df.b = df.b.astype(int)
```

This drops all `NaN` rows from the dataframe, then it converts column `a` and column `b` to an `int`

```
>>> df.dtypes
name    object
a        int32
a1      object
b        int32
b1      object
dtype: object

>>> df
     name       a       a1       b       b1
0  arnold  300311  arnld01  300311  arnld01
1     sam  300713    sam01  300713    sam01
```

#### Fill `NaN` with placeholder data

This option will replace all your `NaN` values with a throw away value. That value is something you need to determine. For this test, I made it `-999999`. This will allow use to keep the rest of the data, convert it to an int, and make it obvious what data is invalid. You'll be able to filter these rows out if you are making calculations based on the columns later.

```
df.fillna(-999999, inplace=True)
df.a = df.a.astype(int)
df.b = df.b.astype(int)
```

This produces a dataframe like so:

```
>>> df.dtypes
name    object
a        int32
a1      object
b        int32
b1      object
dtype: object

>>> df
     name       a       a1       b       b1
0  arnold  300311  arnld01  300311  arnld01
1     sam  300713    sam01  300713    sam01
2    test -999999   test01 -999999   test01
```

#### Leave the float values

Finally, another choice is to leave the float values (and `NaN`) and not worry about the non-integer data type.

Answer (score 13):

I know this is an old question, but there are missing options in the current answers.

you can specify the type of the column, in the example should be something like:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', dtype={'a': 'Int32', 'b': 'Int32'})
```

And pandas will set the missing values as `<NA>`

Comment: Nov 2022 - this is the correct answer

Answer (score 3):

I use pandas 1.5.3 and the below code keeps integer values though there are NaN values in the column.

```
df = pd.read_csv("file.csv", dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 2):

Converting Float to Integer values using Pandas read_csv - Working ====================================================

```html
# Importing the dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('WorldWarWeather_Data.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, 3:11].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 2].values
X=X.astype(int)
y=y.astype(int)
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this on a bit of Django code to render formatted dataframes into HTML.

I don't have prior knowledge of column types or number of columns.

There's a high likelihood of `NaN`'s in any column.

I want to set precision on the true floats and leave the integer values as they are.

Set `NaN`'s to an integer value that will never be used (assumed)

Use `convert_dtypes()` to infer the types again without `NaN`'s

Convert dummy value back to `NaN` (or just use Python `None` for this purpose)

```
df.fillna(-999999, inplace=True)
df = df.convert_dtypes()
df = df.replace(-999999, None)
```

Now the integer columns that were inferred as floats because of missing values are correctly identified as integer.

Works on the assumption that there won't be any legitimate values of -999999 in the dataset, safe assumption for this usage.

Note that `convert_dtypes()` changes `float64` to `Float64` and `int64` to `Int64`, something to remember when applying styles etc later:

```
dfs = df.style.format(subset=list(df.select_dtypes(include='Float64')), precision=self.precision, na_rep='')
```

Answer (score 0):

Pandas will convert an integer column to float if empty strings exist within it. Empty strings are interpreted as null values upon import and the conversion of int to float happens because the default missing data indicator  is `np.nan` which is a float underneath.

You do not have to drop your null values to deal with this issue!

Pandas recently introduced a **new missing data indicator: `pd.NA`**

`pd.NA` does not have an innate data type and works a lot better than `np.nan`. However, it should be used within **nullable data types** - another addition to pandas which allows handling of missing data without altering the state of your column.

Considering the above, you have at least two options:

#### 1. Import the data as usual and convert columns to their nullable counterpart

Nullable data types are still experimental so you will have to covnert manually either with `df = df.convert_dtypes()` or perform the operation on one column at a time:

- Nullable integer: `df[col].astype("Int64")` - note the capital `I`
- Nullable float: `df[col].astype("Float64")` - note the capital `F`
- Nullable boolean: `df[col].astype(pd.BooleanDtype())`
- Nullable string: `df[col].astype(pd.StringDtype())` or `df[col].astype("string")`

#### 2. Import all data as strings

`df = pd.read_csv("data.csv", dtype="string")`

This gives all columns the nullable string type and prevents null values from taking `np.nan` in the first place. You may then proceed to assign the desired data type yourself.