# How to create a dataframe from data queried from SQL QUERY with the correct data types for each column

Tags: python-3.x, pyodbc

I have created a function in python that queries data directly from SQL database using the pyodbc library. The problem is that pd.read_csv in the function generates a dataframe where columns expected to be integers are floats and columns with strings have extra spaces after the column values. How do i resolve this problem?

Here is a sample of the code

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
def query(sql_query):
    conn = pyodbc(connection details)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    df = pd.read_csv(sql_query, conn)
    return df
```

Expected

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | value1 |
| 2 | value2 |

Output

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 1.0 | 'value1 ' |
| 2.0 | 'value2 ' |

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pd.read\_csv by default treats integers like floats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39666308/pd-read-csv-by-default-treats-integers-like-floats)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43332057/strip-whitespace-from-strings-in-a-column and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39666308/pd-read-csv-by-default-treats-integers-like-floats